# Como volver a ejecutar un programa en python?

Tags: python, ejecutar

mi consulta de hoy surge debido a que necesito que un código, luego de terminarse, vuelva a ejecutarse automáticamente. Busqué gente que haya consultado lo mismo y la respuesta que le daban era que eso se lograba con un ciclo While, pero en mi caso, cuando lo hago, se crea un bucle infinito. Puede ser que haya sido error mio al ejecutarlo también. Les dejo el código a continuación. Edito para hacer una aclaración,necesito que el codigo se ejecute tantas veces como el usuario lo requiera, y, al realizar un ciclo While y colocarle un break, el problema que me surge es que no puedo ver el resultado que el programa debe ejecutar ya que se cierra de inmediato, no se qué error estaría cometiendo.
Desde ya, gracias.

````
import math
from fractions import Fraction 
a = int (input('Ingrese valor de A: '))
b = int (input('Ingrese valor de B: '))
c = int (input('Ingrese el valor de C: '))
y = b ** 2 - 4 * a * c 

if y>0 :
    p = ( -b + math.sqrt(y) ) / (2 * a) 
    print(f'X1 = {round(p, 2)} // {Fraction(p)}') 
    n = ( -b - math.sqrt(y) ) / (2 * a) 
    print(f'X2 = {round(n,2)} // {Fraction(n)}')
else : 
    print('No tiene resultado real') ```
````

Comment: Cuantas veces quieres que se ejecute? O dicho de otra manera, cuando debe parar?

Comment: Lo normal es usar un ciclo while si no sabemos el número de iteraciones en un inicio ya que dependerá de alguna condición o for si sabemos las veces que vamos a iterar desde el inicio. Debes especificar cuantas iteraciones quieres o cuando debe dejar de iterar, así como que parte del código debe ejecutarse de nuevo y cuál una sola vez. Si usas un ciclo while la condición del mismo debe evaluarse como False en algún momento o romper el ciclo desde dentro con break, en caso contrario tendrás un ciclo infinito como comentas.

Comment: Ahí modifiqué la pregunta y aclaré, seguí intentando crear un ciclo while pero no logro hacerlo correctamente, si alguien me puede iluminar estoy agradecido!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Al realizar una consulta desde el principio podemos evitar el bucle.
2. Manejamos de igual forma `.isnumeric()` para blindar los campos y evitar
   que metan alguna letra o espacio.
3. Y rompemos el bucle al indicarle a la opción de salir

   ```
   import math 
   from fractions import Fraction

   while (True):
       print("""Bienvendido en que te puedo ayudar
       1) Quiero una operación
       2) Salir""")
       opcion =input()
       if opcion =="1":
           a = input('Ingrese valor de A: ')
           b = input('Ingrese valor de B: ')
           c = input('Ingrese valor de C: ')
           if a.isnumeric() and b.isnumeric() and c.isnumeric():
               a = int(a)
               b = int(b)
               c = int(c)
               y = b ** 2 - 4 * a * c 
               if y > 0 :
                       p = ( -b + math.sqrt(y) ) / (2 * a) 
                       print(f'X1 = {round(p, 2)} // {Fraction(p)}') 
                       n = ( -b - math.sqrt(y) ) / (2 * a) 
                       print(f'X2 = {round(n,2)} // {Fraction(n)}')
               else : 
                   print('No tiene resultado real')      
           else:
               print("Los parametros introducidos deben ser números vuelva a intentarlo")

       elif opcion=="2":
           print("Que pases un buen dia")
           break
       else:
           print("El Numero introduccido es erroneo")
   ```

## Y así quedaría

[image: Y así quedaría]

Answer (score 0):

No se entiende bien la pregunta, pero intentaré ayudar con algunos conceptos.
Para ejecutar una rutina una cantidad indeterminada de veces, te puedes apoyar con un ciclo `while`, además de un tiempo de espera en segundos `time.sleep(#seg)`, como muestro en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
import time, math
from fractions import Fraction 
def main():
    a = int (input('Ingrese valor de A: '))
    b = int (input('Ingrese valor de B: '))
    c = int (input('Ingrese el valor de C: '))
    y = b ** 2 - 4 * a * c 

    if y>0 :
        p = ( -b + math.sqrt(y) ) / (2 * a) 
        print(f'X1 = {round(p, 2)} // {Fraction(p)}') 
        n = ( -b - math.sqrt(y) ) / (2 * a) 
        print(f'X2 = {round(n,2)} // {Fraction(n)}')
    else : 
        print('No tiene resultado real')

while True:
    main()
    time.sleep(10) # Espera 10 segundos
```

Una forma más "sexy" de salir del `while` puede ser, reescribiendo esa parte:

```
print("** Presione CTRL+C para salir **")
while True:
    try: 
        main()
        time.sleep(10)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\n Ejecucion interrumpida por el usuario \n")
        time.sleep(1)
        break
```

La segunda opción es que una *entidad externa* ejecute el script en una cantida de tiempo. Esa entidad puede ser un programa, el programador de tareas, u otro script.

Ejecutar un script desde otro es un tema bastante avanzado, pero un código muy básico, utilizando el modulo [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html), podría ser el que mostraré a continuación. A groso modo Subprocess es un módulo para crear nuevos procesos o ejecutar aplicaciones o comandos en el sistema (ver la documentación).

Crea un archivo llamado `main1.py` y en el va el código que publicaste
Crea otro archivo llamado, por ejemplo, `runner.py` con algo como:

```
import subprocess, time

    print("** Presione CTRL+C para salir **")
    while True:
        try:
            subprocess.run("python main1.py") # subprocess.run [Python 3.5 o superior]
            time.sleep(10)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("\n Ejecucion terminada por el usuario \n")
            time.sleep(1)
            break
```

Desde `runner.py` se ejecutará el otro script en el rango de tiempo determinado. `subprocess.run` esperará a que termine la ejecución de `main1.py` para continuar con el ciclo.
Con esa información espero que ya puedes hacer las adaptaciones que requieres.